# Why does this code cause a segmentation fault in Node.js v0.10.31 on a Mac?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var foo, bar;
foo = new Uint8Array(20000);
bar = new Uint8Array(20000);
for (i = 0, j = 0; i < foo.length; i += 2, j += 2) {
    bar[i + 0] = foo[j + 0];
    bar[i + 1] = foo[j + 1];
    bar[i + 1] = foo[j + 1];
}
```

I realise that this routine makes no sense, especially the duplicated line, but this is a vastly reduced version of a real routine that has an actual purpose and appears to cause the same issue.

What I'm looking for is an explanation, if possible, on why it consistently crashes node.js.

For the record, it fails when i and j hit 11780.

Comment: It doesn't crash for me on Windows with node v0.10.30.

Comment: You might want to try to investigate the issue yourself: https://github.com/ddopson/node-segfault-handler

Comment: Strange, I've tried it on three machines here, all macs with v0.10.31, and they all give the same result.

Comment: @GitaarLAB I can't see how that would help being as there are no modules involved in the above example.

Comment: I've now edited the question to more explicitly reference the platform and version.

Comment: [segfault-handler](https://github.com/ddopson/node-segfault-handler) also handles "native core". As you can see, the [OP in the thread](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8208) that [Volune](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2191722/volune) linked to also used it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Known bug in node 0.10.31](https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/8208), stick with 0.10.30 until the fix has been released.